# How can I use number Value in react-testing-library userEvent

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, user-event

Recently, I am changing fireEvent to userEvent. If the type value of userEvent is number, a type error occurs, but is it not possible to use the number type for the value in userEvent?

```
  await userEvent.type(
    screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'pay' }),
   1000 //type error
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userEvent.type` expects a string because that's how it represents sequences of keys being pressed. You can fix this specific example by changing `1000` to `'1000'`. If you need to do this dynamically, you can use `.toString()` instead.